# Long wait time in cross database SQL Server queries

Tags: sql-server, wait, cross-database

I've encountered a bizarre problem with a cross-database query in production under SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. I am not able to create this in my development environments, so I'm thinking it's something with the server's configuration, which was installed with default settings as a named instance.

This is not a query execution performance issue; it is a database connection issue.

Take the following query (MyTable has around 100 rows in it):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyDatabase..MyTable
```

Execution time runs around 4 seconds. According to Client Statistics, Client Processing time is 0 with "Wait time on server replies" making up the other four seconds of the execution time.

If I first execute `USE MyDatabase` and then execute my query, it's instant. If I execute them in sequence:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyDatabase..MyTable
```

It still takes the extended amount of time as the `USE MyDatabase` statement takes a long time to execute. It does not matter whether or not the table name is fully qualified with the database name, nor does using synonyms change things. In the past I ran into something similar and `DBCC CHECKDB(<dbname>)` seemed to repair it, but this time around I am unable to get it to behave appropriately. The `wait_type` in `sys.dm_exec_requests` for the connection is the typical `IO_COMPLETION` with a `suspended` SPID status.  I have attempted to repair and restart the system with no luck. This sort of thing strikes me as having its roots in an authentication issue, but I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Added:

I occasionally get a `Database 'MyDatabase' is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished` message. I have executed a full repair using the SQL Server 2012 installation tools as well. Any ideas?

Comment: If that really works, you should post it as an answer, accept it and delete your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the cause was the AUTO_CLOSE property of the databases. Turning this off `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF WITH NO_WAIT` seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Just curious - it looks like your issue isn't with the cross-database join but with the USE statement, right?  I wish you had captured SET STATISTICS TIME ON as part of your solution, as that would more clearly explain where the bottleneck was.

Comment: This was a long time ago and I'm not sure if the issue applies to newer versions of SQL Server. I believe the issue was with having an open connection to the database. While the client application used connection pooling that would retain open database connections, the database itself had views that did cross-database joins to static 3rd party data that was only used by the application (historical weather). I believe the AUTO_CLOSE setting would allow the 3rd party database to drop offline if nothing was connected. The initial "USE" statement ensured the connection existed prior to the query.